# Print XML on Zebra printer using Python

Tags: python, xml, printing, zebra-printers

In my work place, we have a Dymo printer that picks up data from a database and place it in a template label that I made, it prints with python automatically with a program.
Recently we bought a Zebra Thermal Printer, and I need to update the program to do the same thing, but with the Zebra printer.
I was looking around, and I found the ZebraDesigner for XML and I design a few labels like the ones I need it, but the zebra package for python is not able to print XML format, and I tried to print .lbl format but I wasn't able.
Note that .lbl files can't be edit as a text... And I need to do this...
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a way to make this.
With ZebraDesigner (not pro) I design the label template to my automated labels and I export to a file changing the route of the printer in Windows Preferences.
With the Online ZPL viewer of Labelary and minimum knowledges of ZPL (always with the manual near) I modified the label to make it editable on python with the use of .format() and {0},{1}, etc.
And finally done this, I call a batch with the command `PRINT 'FILE' 'ZEBRAPORT'` like `PRINT C:\FILE.ZPL USB003` to print the specific modified label.
If someone want specific code of how I do this please, just ask me.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to do this as well! Could you help me with that? Same situation: python and windows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course, please, explain me what you want to do?
You need basics of ZPL and the Online Viewer I specified, and later, with python is  to easy to replace with the `format()` command.
By this time, I was using a batch file to call the system print command to print the label, but now, I am using the `win32print` library for python to manage the printing.